# Randomize images on imageview with "if" function working strange

Tags: android, image, android-studio, if-statement, random

I'm trying to randomize images when a button is clicked and if the image is what I want it to be, randomize again, but if it's not, close the activity.

I cant randomize in my code, it closes always, but if I delete the call to the `finish()` function, it will randomize normally.

I just want that imageview to recognize the image without a sqlite DB

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int[] cards={R.drawable.bg,R.drawable.bg1};
                Random r = new Random();
                int n = r.nextInt(2);
                ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
                imgview1.setImageResource(cards[n]);

                if (imgview1.equals(R.drawable.bg){
                    imgview1.setImageResource(cards[n]);
                }
                else  {
                    finish();
                }
            }
```

Comment: No, it will return 0 or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this condition `if (imgview1.equals(R.drawable.bg)` to

`if (cards[n ] == R.drawable.bg)`

Your problem is that you are comparing the ImageView reference to the ImageResource

Answer (score 1):

Your `Activity` always closes because you compare `ImageView` and `Resource`, it always false. To provide logic which you want, you can use `setTag()` method, to set tag as image resource and then compare them:

```
ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
imgview1.setImageResource(cards[n]);
imgview1.setTag(cards[n]);

if (imgview1.getTag().equals(R.drawable.bg) {
    imgview1.setImageResource(cards[n]);
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `if-condition` is always false because you are comparing an `Object` to an `int` which will never be true.

Unfortunately there is no `ImageView#getDrawableId` so you have to use a work around with `Imageview#setTag` e.g.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int[] cards = {
        R.drawable.bg,
        R.drawable.bg1
    };
    int id = cards[new Random().nextInt(2)];
    ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
    imgview1.setImageResource(id);
    imgview1.setTag(id);

    if (imgview1.getTag() == R.drawable.bg) {
        imgview1.setImageResource(id);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: here's a problem, the buttons only works for the next images, not the present

Answer (score 0):

here
1)if condition misses One bracket.
(imgview1.equals(R.drawable.bg))

2) Compare Image With int Because R.drawble.bg gives You Resource ID that not match..thats why its always goes to else

Solution:

```
ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
    imgview1.setImageResource(id);
    imgview1.setTag(id);

    if (imgview1.getTag() == R.drawable.bg) {
        imgview1.setImageResource(id);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
```